# How can I get 8050-3 Registration amended?

Tags: aircraft-registration

How can I get 8050-3 Registration amended? Box 2 (Aircraft Manufacturer and Model) on 8050-1 Application shows 'MylastName, MyFirstName' and RV 9A as the Model.  When I got my 8050-3 Registration back, the box 'Manufacturer and Manufacturer's Designation of Aircraft' says: VANS AIRCRAFT, INC RV-9A which does not match Manufacturer (Me) on 8050-3 Registration.  This could be a problem when I apply for my Repairman's Certificate where I must be the manufacturer.  I tried contacting FAA.  NG by phone.   Sent Email.  No answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

Paragraph 19 of [the document entitled "INFORMATION TO AID IN THE REGISTRATION OF U.S. CIVIL AIRCRAFT" published by the FAA's Aircraft Registration Branch](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/media/Reg-AR-94.pdf) states:

> CONVEYANCES SUBMITTED FOR THE RECORD
>
> 19. AMENDMENT. An amendment (such as to the date, the description of the collateral, the title of the signer, names of the parties, etc.)
>     may be submitted to amend, correct or clarify any instrument which is
>     on file with the Aircraft Registration Branch. The amendment should
>     state its purpose and describe the original instrument by date,
>     parties, collateral, and, if recorded, the FAA recording number and
>     date. The amendment must be signed by the parties to the original
>     conveyance. The recording fee is $5 for each item of collateral
>     affected.

The document states the mailing address to where you send the amendment request.